# How to export an excel sheet two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl, excel-writer-xlsx

I need to create an excel sheet for each station_list value and write two dataframes in it

```
dfVentaPotencial = ventaPotencial()
print(dfVentaPotencial.head)
```

```
CodigoEstacion  Dia  0am  1am  2am  3am  4am  5am  6am  7am  8am  9am  10am  11am  12pm  1pm  2pm   3pm  4pm  5pm  6pm  7pm  8pm  9pm  10pm  11pm
0             60008    1    4   42    0    5    4   41   56  176    0   22     0   649     0  182  227   118  176  135    0  150  112  235   118    17
1             60008    2   37    0   13    0    0   27   11    0    0    0     9   439   601  463  715  1027  706  617  172    0    0  192   151    22
2             60008    3    2   16    2   11    0   38   98    0    0    0     0     0     0    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0   97     0   114
3             60008    4   23    9   12    7    2    0    0   73    0    0     0     0     0    0    0     0    0    0  510  457    0   60     0    49
4             60008    5    0    0    0   23    3   58  129    0    0    0     0   328     0    0    0   575    0    0  121   87  300   73    68     0
..              ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...  ...  ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...
925           60999   27   16    0    2    0   11    0    0   73    0    0    80    78   128   32    0     0   81  239   86   89  176    0     0     0
926           60999   28    0    0    6    0   36   64    0    0    0    0     0   109   365    0  113     0    0    0   48   21  149    0     0     0
927           60999   29    0   45    4    0   13   16   12    0   72   84    40     0    48    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0    5     0     0
928           60999   30    0    2    8    5   11    0    0   95    0    0     0    63    92    0    2    30    0    0  270    0    0   34     0     0
929           60999   31   16    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0
```

```
dfTrxAtendedor = trxAtendedores()
dfTrxAtendedor = pd.pivot_table(dfTrxAtendedor,values='trxXAtendedor',index=["CodigoEstacion","Dia"],columns="Hora",fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(dfTrxAtendedor.head)
```

```
 Hora  CodigoEstacion  Dia  0am  1am  2am  3am  4am  5am  6am  7am  8am  9am  10am  11am  12pm  1pm  2pm  3pm  4pm  5pm  6pm  7pm  8pm  9pm  10pm  11pm
0              60008    1    4    0    0    0    0    0    4    6   10    8    16    10    21   15   18   18   14   13   16   12   12    7     7     8
1              60008    2    2    2    0    2    0    2    3    4    6    8    11    15    20   23   10   13   15   16   18   19   14    4     6     4
2              60008    3    0    0    0    0    1    6    9   14   10   14    15    12    13   15   12   13   12   16   18   19   15    7     7     4
3              60008    4    0    0    0    0    0    6   11   12   13   16    12    16    12    9   13   14   19   18   17   16   13    7     9     4
4              60008    5    2    2    0    0    0    4    4   12   15   13    14    12    13   14   11   10   15   18   19   17   15   10     8    19
..               ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...
925            60999   27    1    2    0    1    0    3    7   10   22   14    11    14     4    8   12   18   14   16   18   14   15   14     8     2
926            60999   28    1    1    1    1    0    1    6    7   16   14    12     9     4   16   14   14   16   14   18   16   10   13     4     4
927            60999   29    3    0    0    1    0    1    2    3    6   12    12    14    14   11   15   14    7   13   13   11   10    6     5     3
928            60999   30    2    0    0    0    0    2    2    1    6    9     8     6     8    9   12    8    9   12    8   14    8    6     2     2
```

I have been trying this loop but I am getting the following error

```
estation_list = [60008, 60012,60021,60048,60050,60053,60055,60072,60074,60078,60079,60088,60096,60134,60135,60139,60265,60268,60371,60411,60512,60517,60610,60664,60773,60783,60814,60840,60890,60999]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for estation in estation_list:
    dataframe_collection = {}
    dataframe_collection[estation] = dfTrxAtendedor[dfTrxAtendedor["CodigoEstacion"] == estation]
    dataframe_collection[estation] = dfVentaPotencial[dfVentaPotencial["CodigoEstacion"] == estation]
    dataframe_collection.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=estation)
writer.save()
```

```
 dataframe_collection.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=estation)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

I am new to phyton I am trying this method since I need to format the cells and with pandas it seems that it cannot be, so I intend to generate the excel file with the n sheets according to station_list, then edit these files with openpyxl and finish exporting the sheets in format PDF

Comment: `dataframe_collection = {}` is your problem. You probably want to work directly with a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary with multiple dfs in it. You cannot export the complete dict but you can export the underlying df:

```
dataframe_collection[estation].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=estation)
```

Comment: Oh thanks, this works but it is only leaving me one dataframe per sheet and I need 3 dataframes per sheet. I guess it's because this is overwriting the value of dataframe_collection[estation]

Comment: I solved it by interleaving       dataframe_collection[estation] = dfTrxAtendedor[dfTrxAtendedor["CodigoEstacion"] == estation]
        dataframe_collection[estation].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(estation), startrow=17, startcol=5)
        dataframe_collection[estation] = dfVentaPotencial[dfVentaPotencial["CodigoEstacion"] == estation]
        dataframe_collection[estation].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(estation), startrow=50, startcol=5)

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go :) Please set the question as resolved if that's the case.